# Can't tab inside select tag

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select

Is moving in option menu possible just using tab without adding extra JavaScript? I tried using tabindex but it doesn't work and it seems that only option is to add eventListener but maybe there is simple practical solution which I'm not familiar with, which not include JS?
[image]

```
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: I don't get the question though. Hitting tab just focuses the select and you can activate it by hitting space.

Comment: Thank you maybe now it's more clear